# Stand alone Zend Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I can use Zend form as a stand alone component when I am creating forms using the following code:

```
set_include_path(
implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    get_include_path(),
    PATH_TO_ZF_LIBRARY
)));

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$form = new Zend_Form;

... create and add zend form elements here

//display form
echo $form->render(new Zend_View());
```

However, I cannot I figure out how I can add custom form elements and validation. I created custom element and validation form phone number and social security number.  But I cannot add them to a stand alone form.
Could someone kindly advice?  I thank you all in advance.

Comment: @Keyne : In the library folder I have a folder called My.  I put all my custom code there.  I have My/Form/Element/Phone.php in there. I also have My/View/Helper/PhoneElement.php and My/Validate Phone.php.  But when I do  `$hPhone = new My_Form_Element_Phone( 'hphone' );` I get `Fatal error: Class 'My_Form_Element_Phone' not found`.  It seems that the form knows how to load zend components but it does not know how to load components from the folder My.  How do I tell it to that?

Comment: So, you need to register the name space as said in the answer bellow.

Comment: Did the answer I gave solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to register the namespace that you want with the autoloader.

The autoloader will, by default, only load Zend components.

It looks like in your case you'll want to do the following

`$autoloader->registerNamespace( 'My' );`

Make sure the library folder is in your include path.

You should then be able to use/autoload your My components.